# ZeroMQ context not initializing on Windows Server 2012 machine

Tags: c#, zeromq

I am using ZeroMQ with combination of clrzmq and libzmq dll files.

I have included these files in my windows service project and it was working fine in simple windows PC. Now I moved service to Windows Server 2012 machine where I installed service with administrator rights and trying to start ZMQ server. All attempts to start server are getting failed with below error.

**My Code**

```
        public void InitializeServer()
        {
            using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
            {
                using (var socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP))
                {
                    HelperMethods.WriteLog(string.Format("server started at: {0}", serverAddress));
                    socket.Bind(serverAddress);

                    while (true)
                    {
                        lock (_lock)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var rcvdMsg = socket.Receive(Encoding.UTF8);
                                HelperMethods.WriteLog("New event received. ");
                                var replyMsg = "Acknowledged event.";
                                HelperMethods.WriteLog(replyMsg);
                                socket.Send(replyMsg, Encoding.UTF8);
                                HelperMethods.WriteLog("=====================================================");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                HelperMethods.WriteLog("InitializeServer(): " + ex.Message + " | Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**ERROR:**

> The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.Interop.LibZmq' threw an exception. |
>   at ZeroMQ.Interop.ContextProxy.Initialize() in
>   C:\clrzmq\zeromq-clrzmq-v3.0.0-beta1-52-g0d83a1e\zeromq-clrzmq-0d83a1e\src\ZeroMQ\Interop\ContextProxy.cs:line
>   28    at ZeroMQ.ZmqContext.Create() in
>   C:\clrzmq\zeromq-clrzmq-v3.0.0-beta1-52-g0d83a1e\zeromq-clrzmq-0d83a1e\src\ZeroMQ\ZmqContext.cs:line 78

**What I have tried so far**

- I have installed C++ redistributable package.
- I have disabled firewall and added service exe inbound and outbound
  rules
- I have installed .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: Did you try NetMQ? a port of zeromq to c#, might be simpler. https://github.com/zeromq/netmq

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718262/zeromq-dllnotfoundexception-using-net-bindings) post and solved my problem.
For anyone else who is facing same problem, please try downloading & installing the VS2010 C++ redistributable..